# using adist on two columns of data frame

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I want to use adist to calculate edit distance between the values of two columns in each row.

I am using it in more-or-less this way:

```
A <- c("mad","car")
B <- c("mug","cat")
my_df <- data.frame(A,B)
my_df$dist <- adist(my_df$A, my_df$B, ignore.case = TRUE)
my_df <- my_df[order(dist),]
```

The last two rows are the same as in my case, but the actual data frame looks a bit different - columns of my original data frame are character type, not factor. Also, the dist column seems to be returned as 2-column matrix, I have no idea why it happens.

Update:
I have read a bit and found that I need to apply it over the rows, so my new code is following:

```
apply(my_df, 1, function(d) adist(d[1], d[2]))
```

It works fine, but for my original dataset calling it by column numbers is inpractical, how can I refer to column names in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome that problem by using `mapply`, i.e.

```
mapply(adist, df$A, df$B)
#[1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `tidyverse` approach, you may use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
A <- c("mad","car")
B <- c("mug","cat")
my_df <- data.frame(A,B)

my_df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Lev_dist=adist(x=A,y=B,ignore.case=TRUE))
```

Comment: I have used `mapply` as a simpler approach, but still thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

As per `adist` function definition the `x` and `y` arguments should be character vectors. In your example the function is returning a 2x2 matrix because it is comparing also the cross words "mad" with "cat" and "car" with "mug".

Just look at the matrix master diagonal.

Comment: I just found about having to use `apply` here, updated the opening post.